# mySQL Insert into table with foreign key ID from another

Tags: php, sql, insert, foreign-keys

I have two tables:
p_model: (id auto inc), (name), (p_category_id) **AND** p_category: (id), (name)

Basically every model is associated by a category. I need to generate a INSERT statement that inserts a new model and adds the id of the p_category associated to it.

My PHP Function Passes both values:

```
function Perform_Insert_Model($model_name, $category_name)
{
$statement = "INSERT INTO p_model(`name`,`p_category_id`) VALUES ('$model_name','??????')";

//Where the "??????" is I need a statement that searches for $category_name (string) in the p_category table and returns the id.

....
}
```

An example call to the function would be $database->Perform_Insert_Model("Banana","Fruit"). Banana would then be a new product model and have a foreign key association of fruit's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this kind of query (this is just 1 query):

```
INSERT INTO p_model(`name`,`p_category_id`) SELECT '$model_name', `p_category_id`
   FROM p_category WHERE `category_name`='$category_name';
```

Note: this assumes there is only 1 category by the given category_name or it will insert multiple records in p_model

Comment: Perfect thanks. It didn't work exactly because it needed SELECT 'id' rather then SELECT '$model_name'. I ended up using (note i changed the name of the tables): INSERT INTO product(`model`,`type_id`) SELECT '$p_model_name', `id` FROM `product_types` WHERE `desc` = '$p_type_name'